# EF code first many to many relation when no relation in DB

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, ef-code-first

Suppose I have two classes model like:

```
 public class AuthorityUser
{
    public string GUID { get; set; } 
    public int UserID { get; set; } 
    public ICollection<Authority1> Authorities { get; set; }
    public AuthorityUser()
    {
        Authorities = new HashSet<Authority1>();
    } 
}
public partial class Authority1
{
    public virtual int AID
    {
        get;
        set;
    }   
    public virtual ICollection<AuthorityUser> AuthorityUsers { get; set; }
    public Authority1()
    { 
        AuthorityUsers = new HashSet<AuthorityUser>();
    }
}
```

I am going to make Many To Many relation between them based on `UserAuthorityMap` connected table in DB.

so I did this to make M:N relation in `OnModelCreating()`

```
modelBuilder.Entity<AuthorityUser>().ToTable("Gainer").HasKey(x => x.UserID);
modelBuilder.Entity<Authority1>().ToTable("Authority").HasKey(x => x.AID);  
modelBuilder.Entity<AuthorityUser>()
          .HasMany<Authority1>(s => s.Authorities)
          .WithMany(c => c.AuthorityUsers)
          .Map(cs =>
          {
              cs.MapLeftKey("UserID");
              cs.MapRightKey("AID");
              cs.ToTable("UserAuthorityMap");
          });
```

As I mentioned in title there is no relation between them in DB so the diagram in DB is like picture below :
[image]

when I run this :

```
dbContext.AuthorityUsers.SingleOrDefault(x => x.UserID == 65);
```

the related `Authorities` won't be loaded from DB.

so should I use `HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)` to make it right or something else?

Answer (score 1):

Since `Authorities` navigation property is not `virtual`,  lazy loading has been turned off and thus you have 2 options left to load them.

**Option 1: Eager Loading**

```
dbContext.AuthorityUsers.Include(x => x.Authorities).SingleOrDefault(x => x.UserID == 65);
```

*Note*: `Include` is an extension method in the `System.Data.Entity` namespace so make sure you are using that namespace.

**Option 2: Explicit Loading**

```
var users = dbContext.AuthorityUsers.SingleOrDefault(x => x.UserID == 65);
dbContext.Entry(users).Collection(p => p.Authorities).Load();
```

Please see [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj574232(v=vs.113).aspx) for more details.

Comment: Oh my mistake, thanks I thought for EF existing relation is mandatory in DB, so it doesn't matter relation exist in db or no?.

Comment: However still getting error `The property 'Authorities' on type 'UserAuthority' cannot be set because the collection is already set to an EntityCollection`

Comment: @aria check the FKs in db because I am pretty sure the relationship exists. If not, let me know please.

Comment: No the relation does not exist in DB, just `UserAuthorityMap` table have two PKs `UserId` and `AID`.

Answer (score 1):

If you followed the [Entity Framework Code-First conventions](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/code-first-conventions.aspx) you wouldn't have this problem.

If you really need to use non-conventional names for your tables and your primary keys, then indeed your two ModelBuilder statements for `AuthorityUser` and `Authority` will do what you want.

However, to make your many-to-many relationship easier, reconsider your method, and make your life easier by following the [entity-framework conventions for many-to-many relation](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-many-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx)

In your case this would lead to two changes:

- Make AuthorityUser.Authorities virtual
- Let your classes represent your tables: let it be simple POCOs: no HashSet, no Constructor.

The reason to make your table classes simple POCOs, is because the class represents a table in a database. This table has no HashSet, and if you don't need it, why limit yourself to a HashSet? (See later)

In your case the proper many-to-many without the need tell the model builder that you configured a many-to-many would be:

```
class AuthorityUser
{
    // Primary Key (reconsider: Id)
    public int UserID { get; set; } 
    // an AuthorityUser belongs to zero or more Authorities (many-to-many)
    public virtual ICollection<Authority> Authorities { get; set; }
    ... // other properties
}
class Authority
{
    // primary key (reconsider: Id)
    public int AID {get; set;}
    // an Authority has zero or more AuthorityUsers (many-to-many)  
    public virtual ICollection<AuthorityUser> AuthorityUsers { get; set; }
    ... // other users
}

class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<AuthorityUser> AuthorityUsers {get; set;}
    public DbSet<Authority> Authorities {get; set;}
}
```

You already understood that you need some Model Building to inform entity framework about your non-conventional primary keys and table names.

But removing the HashSet and declaring both ICollections in the many-to-many is enough for entity framework to understand that a many-to-many is intended. You don't need to do some model building for this. Enityt Framework will create a junction table and use it whenever needed.

When using the many-to-many you won't do a join with the junction table. Instead you think in collections:

**Give me all AuthorityUsers that have xxx with their Authorities that have yyy**

```
var result = dbContext.AuthorityUsers
    .Where(authorityUser => xxx)
    .Select(authorityUser => new
    {
        // take only the properties from authorityuser you'll need:
        UserId = authorityUser.UserId,
        GUID = authorityUser.GUID,

        // take all authorities from this authorityUser that have yyy
        Authorities = authorityUser.Authorities
            .Where(authority => yyy)
            .Select(authority => new
            {
                // take only the authority properties you'll use:
                AID = authority.AID,
                ...
            })
            .ToList(),
    });
}
```

Entity Framework knows that this needs two joins with the junction table, and perform the proper SQL statement for you.

The query: give me all Authorities that ... with all their AuthorityUsers which ... is similar.

**Is your hashset needed?**

No, in all your queries, entity framework will replace the HashSet by its own virtual ICollection<...>.

Your HashSet would only be useful if you'd add a new Authority with its AuthorityUsers. Without HashSet this would be like:

```
Authority addedAuthority = myDbContext.Authorieties.Add(new Authority()
    {
         GUID = ...
         ... // other properties

         // this Authority has the following AuthorityUsers:
         AuthorityUsers = new List<AuthorityUsers>()
         {
              new AuthorityUser() {...},
              new AuthorityUser() {...},
              ...
         },
    });
```

Instead of a List you couls assign any ICollection, like an array, or even from a Dictionary:

```
Dictionary<int, AuthorityUser> authorityUsers = ...
Authority addedAuthority = myDbContext.Authorieties.Add(new Authority()
    {
         ...
         // this Authority has the following AuthorityUsers:
         AuthorityUsers = authorityUsers.Values,
    });
```

So you see that removing the HashSet give you more freedom to provide the ICollection: Better reusability. Less code, which makes it better understandable when someone else needs to maintain it. Besides it is a waste of processing power to create a HashSet that is most of the time not used.

Comment: Anyway I fixed the problem but when I want to use it in somewhere else I got `The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection.`, I think I should initiate navigate props manually as you mentioned.

Comment: Make sure the lazy loading codes is executed before you dispose the context. So use ToList() and comparable